# Filtering through a list with embedded dictionaries

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I've got a json format list with some dictionaries within each list, it looks like the following:

```
[{"id":13, "name":"Albert", "venue":{"id":123, "town":"Birmingham"}, "month":"February"},
{"id":17, "name":"Alfred", "venue":{"id":456, "town":"London"}, "month":"February"},
{"id":20, "name":"David", "venue":{"id":14, "town":"Southampton"}, "month":"June"},
{"id":17, "name":"Mary", "venue":{"id":56, "town":"London"}, "month":"December"}]
```

The amount of entries within the list can be up to 100. I plan to present the 'name' for each entry, one result at a time, for those that have London as a town. The rest are of no use to me. I'm a beginner at python so I would appreciate a suggestion in how to go about this efficiently. I initially thought it would be best to remove all entries that don't have London and then I can go through them one by one.

I also wondered if it might be quicker to not filter but to cycle through the entire json and select the names of entries that have the town as London.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
data = [{"id":13, "name":"Albert", "venue":{"id":123, "town":"Birmingham"}, "month":"February"},
        {"id":17, "name":"Alfred", "venue":{"id":456, "town":"London"}, "month":"February"},
        {"id":20, "name":"David", "venue":{"id":14, "town":"Southampton"}, "month":"June"},
        {"id":17, "name":"Mary", "venue":{"id":56, "town":"London"}, "month":"December"}]

london_dicts = filter(lambda d: d['venue']['town'] == 'London', data)
for d in london_dicts:
    print(d)
```

This is as efficient as it can get because:

- The loop is written in C (in case of CPython)
- `filter` returns an iterator (in Python 3), which means that the results are loaded to memory one by one as required

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use list comprehension:

```
>>> data = [{"id":13, "name":"Albert", "venue":{"id":123, "town":"Birmingham"}, "month":"February"},
            {"id":17, "name":"Alfred", "venue":{"id":456, "town":"London"}, "month":"February"},
            {"id":20, "name":"David", "venue":{"id":14, "town":"Southampton"}, "month":"June"},
            {"id":17, "name":"Mary", "venue":{"id":56, "town":"London"}, "month":"December"}]

>>> [d for d in data if d['venue']['town'] == 'London']
[{'id': 17,
  'name': 'Alfred',
  'venue': {'id': 456, 'town': 'London'},
  'month': 'February'},
 {'id': 17,
  'name': 'Mary',
  'venue': {'id': 56, 'town': 'London'},
  'month': 'December'}]
```